# How to access session variable in another perl file

Tags: perl, session

After successful Login, I am setting the session variable in login.pl cgi file.

```
use CGI::Session qw();
my $session = CGI::Session->new;
$session->param(User_id => '12345');
```

I want to access the same User_id in another perl cgi file, say checkout.pl. I am using this to access User_id.

```
use CGI::Session qw();
print $session->param('User_id');
```

But not able to access the value here. Can someone help me, in figuring out what is wrong here. Your help is highly appreciated.

Devesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reinitialize your session in the second request to use it: without this initialization, Perl won't be able to 'guess' what you mean by `$session`. Quoting [the doc](http://search.cpan.org/~sherzodr/CGI-Session-3.95/Session/Tutorial.pm#INITIALIZING_EXISTING_SESSIONS):

> When a user clicks another link or re-visits the site after a short
>   while should we be creating a new session again? Absolutely not. This
>   would defeat the whole purpose of state maintenance. Since we already
>   send the id as a cookie, all we need is to pass that id as the seconds
>   argument while creating a session object:

```
$sid = $cgi->cookie("CGISESSID") || undef;
$session = new CGI::Session(undef, $sid, {Directory=>'/tmp'});
```

> The above syntax will first try to initialize an existing session
>   data, if it fails (if the session doesn't exist) creates a new
>   session: just what we want. But what if the user doesn't support
>   cookies? In that case we would need to append the session id to all
>   the urls as a query string, and look for them in addition to cookie:

```
$sid = $cgi->cookie('CGISESSID') || $cgi->param('CGISESSID') || undef;
$session = new CGI::Session(undef, $sid, {Directory=>'/tmp'});
```

> Assuming you have CGI object handy, you can minimize the above two
>   lines into one:

```
$session = new CGI::Session(undef, $cgi, {Directory=>"/tmp"});
```